# Is it good to connect layers of a website over network?

Tags: ajax, architecture, web, local-network

I am designing architecture of a website. I want to put the work in 3-5 layers like below:

[image: image#1]

[image: image#2]

The main architecture is as shown above. first i want to know that if this is a good one or not in general. But the main question is the method of connecting the layers of the services layer and the data provider layer.

The relation method of the client-side requests would be over network and in the method of AJAX. But what about the server-side of services. Let me describe it more:

one of my services is the main website. A user requests for the page and receives a page. After the page received, other data will be provided as AJAX. from the user (client-side) requesting directly to the data provider layer. But what if I need some data on the service itself when working on server, and before serving the page to the client. I wish I could deliver my opinion to you.

Now I think about two ways:

1) Add an reference of data provider layer in every service and the use it directly by using its classes.

2) The server be a client too. I mean when a service needs data, then make a request to the data provider layer over Intranet. Then I can port every service on a different device in the local network. But the thing is that is the local network good enough to be a good alternative to direct referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it's not a good idea for the client side calling data access layer on the server. I'd rather to provide Restful services API on the server and call only those services in the client side.

In terms of 2 different approaches it depends on you requirements. The first way is definitely faster but if you need more flexibility in scaling out the second may is preferred. It also depends on the size of data being transferred between services and data layer. If they are large so you gotta consider the fact that this data needs to be serialized and deserialized in each call.